# Richtext editor which takes youtube videos

Tags: c#, asp.net, video, youtube, rich-text-editor

Looking for a rich text editor on a aspx admin page which takes images and youtube videos currently using [Current editor](http://www.freetextbox.com/)

Which takes images easily but user wants to upload videos along with images.

[This article contains images and videos in any order](http://www.reckontalk.com/worlds-most-dangerous-deadliest-mad-race-isle-of-man/)

Comment: I don't think RTF supports videos. He could upload a link to a video ...

Comment: You're already using an HTML editor.  Users don't "upload" YouTube videos, they post a link that displays the video (i.e.,` <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9bZkp7q19f0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`).  You can also wrap them in a Video tag (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp).

Comment: Please check the link from top to bottom this is the users requirement. http://www.reckontalk.com/worlds-most-dangerous-deadliest-mad-race-isle-of-man/